# Square root using divide and conquer method code giving sqrt values 1 less than what they should be

Tags: c

```
double findSquareRoot( int value )
{
  //initialize functions and variables
  double low = 0, high = value;
  double mid = ( low + high ) / 2;
  double square = mid * mid;

  if (value == 0 || value == 1)
     {
        return value;
     }
  
  while ( ( high - low ) > SQRT_PRECISION )
     {
        if ( square == value )
           {
              return mid;
           }
        else if ( square > value )
           {
              high = mid;
           }
        else
           {
              low = mid;
           }
        mid = ( low + high ) / 2;
        square = mid * mid;
     }

   return mid;
}
```

On paper this code looks like it should work but its only returning the correct square root values for 12-16. everything else is 1 less than what it should be. ie 36 returns 5, 121 returns 10, 81 returns 8, and so on.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, converting the `double` results to `int` before displaying them? In that case, 5.999999999 (which is pretty close to 6) will show as 5.

Comment: When I calculate the square root of 36 with a precision of `0.1` I get `6.011719`.

Comment: @Chris But, with a precision of `1e-6`, I get `5.9999999106`.

Comment: GIven the binary search method being used, as the function closes in on the square root I would expect it to alternate between above and below the exact square root. For the OP, basic rounding is to add `0.5` to a `float` or `double` and then cast to `int`.

Comment: We need more details to make anything other than guesses, here. What is `SQRT_PRECISION` and how do you call your function and display the results?

Comment: And what about the nefarious user would tries to find the sqrt of a negative value?

Comment: @Fe2O3 that's an imaginary concern.

Comment: @Chris UV for that comment `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

As it is, if we set `SQRT_PRECISION` to `0.00001` and write a very basic `main` function to test your code, we can see that your function works. **Good job!**

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%d: %lf\n", 36, findSquareRoot(36));
}
```

Output when run:

```
36: 5.999999
```

That's pretty close to `6`. If we change `main` a bit we even get the output we expect by not printing any decimal places.

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%d: %.0lf\n", 36, findSquareRoot(36));
}
```

However, if we cast this result to `int`, the fractional portion of the number is discarded and the output is `5`.

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", 36, (int)findSquareRoot(36));
    printf("%d: %d\n", 81, (int)findSquareRoot(81));
}
```

Output:

```
36: 5
81: 8
```

Given the code you've shown us, it stands to reason that the error in your code lies in the code to print the output of `findSquareRoot`.

A basic method of rounding a floating point number to the nearest `int` is to add `0.5` and cast to `int`.

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", 36, (int)(findSquareRoot(36) + 0.5));
    printf("%d: %d\n", 81, (int)(findSquareRoot(81) + 0.5));
}
```

Output:

```
36: 6
81: 9
```